# Getting WISPr tags from a FON authentication portal

Tags: wifi, lynx

I am doing some investigation around wifi captive portals development.

I would like to capture the [WiSPr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISPr) XML tags from a [FON](https://fon.com) authentication captive portal (my neighbours have that active, I have also a roaming account for that).

Trying to authenticating in an iPhone or even a Mac does not cut it, as the equipment detects the captive portal/WIPr tags, and open a dedicated window/mini-browser without any controls; trying to open the page on a Linux/*BSD might not work as the browser user agent / or behaviour won't be recognized as iPhone/Apple.

Sniffing the iPhone transaction also does not cut it, as the web login page of the captive portal is handled in https/TLS (e.g. it is encrypted on the wire).

I also tried `sysdig` in a Linux, and obviously hit again the head on the encrypted transmissions.

`wget` is also not getting satisfying results.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `lynx` in a FreeBSD system; initially used the `-dump` option, that allowed to see the redirects, but only output and not contents ; then discovered the `-source` option, that shows the source/HTML and does not attempt to render it.

I also used the option `-useragent` to pretend I was an iPhone doing WISPr discovery, and also tried to get one of the pages the iPhone tries to get to discover *if* it is dealing with a captive portal (http://www.apple.com/library/test/sucess.html).

I also had to deal with the fact the FON captive portal is self-signed(?), or my FreeBSD does not know the underlying SSL root certificate. (I did not lost much time tracing that); I just had to configure lynx to accept self-signed certificates (will write the question later on and had a link here).

So the actual commands I used where:

```
lynx -useragent=CaptiveNetworkSupport -dump http://www.apple.com/library/test/sucess.html
```

and however, while the first has it´s usefulness, the one that interested me more was:

```
lynx -useragent=CaptiveNetworkSupport -source http://www.apple.com/library/test/sucess.html
```

Using the latter command line, gave me back the HTML source in it´s full glory with the embedded WISPr tags.

From `man lynx`

> ```
>   -dump  dumps  the  formatted  output  of  the default document or those
>           specified on  the  command  line  to  standard  output.   Unlike
>           interactive mode, all documents are processed.  This can be used
>           in the following way:
>
>           lynx -dump http://www.subir.com/lynx.html
>
>           Files specified on the command line are  formatted  as  HTML  if
>           their  names  end  with one of the standard web suffixes such as
>           ".htm" or ".html".  Use the -force_html option to  format  files
>           whose names do not follow this convention.
>
>   -source
>           works  the  same  as  dump  but  outputs  HTML source instead of
>           formatted text.  For example
>
>           lynx -source . >foo.html
>
>           generates  HTML  source  listing  the  files  in   the   current
>           directory.   Each  file  is  marked  by  an HREF relative to the
>           parent directory.  Add a  trailing  slash  to  make  the  HREF's
>           relative to the current directory:
>
>           lynx -source ./ >foo.html
> ```

taken from the captured login page:

```
<!-- WISPr message -->^M
<span class="displayNone"><!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>^M
<WISPAccessGatewayParam xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.acmewisp.com/WISPAccessGatewayParam.xsd">^M
<Redirect>^M
<AccessProcedure>1.0</AccessProcedure>^M
<LoginURL>https://xxxx/captive/noswifi?hmac=xxxx&amp;res=notyet&amp;uamip=xxxx&amp;uamport=80&amp;userurl=&amp;challenge=xxxxxxe&amp;nasid=BC-14-01-XX-XX-XX&amp;mac=00-15-AF-XX-XX-XX</LoginURL>^M
<AbortLoginURL>http://xxxx:80/captive/logoff</AbortLoginURL>^M
<MessageType>100</MessageType>^M
<ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>^M
<AccessLocation>FonZON:PT</AccessLocation>^M
</Redirect>^M
</WISPAccessGatewayParam>-->^M
</span>
```