# Implementing a Captive portal using Apache

Tags: apache-httpd

I have been trying to build a captive portal in Apache that I plan to be Apple CNA aware.

I found several relevant posts in StackOverflow, including [Captive portal popups...](https://serverfault.com/questions/679393/captive-portal-popups-the-definitive-guide) and [How to create WiFi popup login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891706/ios7-and-captive-portals-changes-to-apple-request-url).

I defined the relevant Apache configuration as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CaptiveNetworkSupport(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.2.1/captive/portal.html [L,R=302]

# android
RedirectMatch 302 /generate_204 http://192.168.2.1/captive/portal.html

# windows
RedirectMatch 302 /ncsi.txt http://192.168.2.1/captive/portal.html
```

It is not working quite right, as the CNA browser enters a redirect loop.

I also tried putting all my relevant pages into a /captive directory, and defining the rule

```
RewriteRule !^captive($|/) http://192.168.2.1/captive/portal.html [L,R=302]
```

But had similar loop problems. What to do?

Comment: Hello; I am now struggling with a similar problem; I am using `create_ap` to start network, which in turn deals with `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`. I wonder what the simplest solution would be for my use case https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446114/can-i-get-dnsmasq-to-drop-any-address-queries-it-does-not-know - it would be great to hear what you say. I thought what is left for me is to tweak iptables and apache. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon investigating and doing some tests, it is evident the Apple CNA is a web browser of its own; evidently if an exception is not properly made, all subsequent requests will have yet again the same user agent. So it will start the procedure/portal redirection from scratch, thus the redirect loops.

So in the rule for Apple, we won't redirect anymore *if* the destination host is the captive portal server.

```
# apple
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CaptiveNetworkSupport(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^192.168.2.1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.2.1/captive/portal.html [L,R=302]

# android
RedirectMatch 302 /generate_204 http://192.168.2.1/captive/portal.html

# windows
RedirectMatch 302 /ncsi.txt http://192.168.2.1/captive/portal.html
```

We also add a generic catch-all rule here, that if none of the previous conditions happen, or we are dealing with a OS which we do not have a rule for, it will redirect to the portal *if not already there* (e.g. not visiting the captive directory).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/captive/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.168.2.1/captive/portal.html [L]
```

Obviously, I would stress out that with this configuration, all the captive portal specific files have to live below the /captive directory.

See also [Captive portal detection, popup implementation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212871/captive-portal-detection-popup-implementation/421402#421402)

Comment: I'd like to add that it's also useful to redirect any 404 to the captive portal with `ErrorDocument 404 /captive/portal.html`.

Comment: @MarcoMartinelli Thanks for the comment! We encounter a few tibdbits about the theme here and there, hence also having published those questions in the past.